# Search Insert Position

Tags: python

I'm solving a problem (leetcode 35). My code returns null for test case
input: [1,3,5,6], 7. Couldn't find out the bug.

Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.

You may assume no duplicates in the array.

```
Example 1:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 5
Output: 2
Example 2:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 2
Output: 1
Example 3:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 7
Output: 4
Example 4:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 0
Output: 0
```

below my code. i understand this question has many different solutions and my solution is not optimal. but please just help me understand where the bug is instead of giving a completely new solution. thanks!

```
class Solution(object):
    def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        try:
            return nums.index(target)
        except:
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                print i
                if nums[i] - target > 0:
                    return i
                else: 
                    print "hello", len(nums)
                    return len(nums)
```

Comment: Why did you put the function inside a class? Does the class have any attributes?

Comment: @GeeTransit I think that's just the way the solution is constructed for the challenge (probably java developers imposing poor python practises).

Comment: Looks like it. I'll pretend it's just a function on its own.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/search-insert-position/  that's just how the problem is presented. not important to my bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first part is correct, use `list.index` and catch an exception. However your second part (without prints)

```
  for i in range(len(nums)):
      if nums[i] - target > 0:
          return i  # return if True
      else: 
          return len(nums)  # return if False
```

This means that the first iteration of the `for` loop will always return no matter what.

You need to bring the `else` block out of the for loop; something like this:

```
def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
    try:
        return nums.index(target)
    except IndexError:  # best to use explicit except
        for index, value in enumerate(nums):  # more pythonic than range(len(nums))
             if value > target:
                  return index
        return len(nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of your solution is [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and that's not so bad, but we can achieve better performance [O(log n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) if we will use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20binary%20search,middle%20element%20of%20the%20array.).

```
class Solution:
  def searchInsert(self, array: List[int], target: int) -> int:
      low = 0
      high = len(array)

      while low < high:
          middle = (high + low) // 2

          if array[middle] == target:
              return middle

          if array[middle] < target:
             low = middle + 1

          if array[middle] > target:
             high = middle - 0
    return low
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out!

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        nums.append(target)         
        nums.sort()                 
        for i,j in enumerate(nums): 
            if target == j:         
                return i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution(object):
    def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if target in nums:
            return (nums.index(target))
        else:
            nums.append(target)
            nums.sort()
            return(nums.index(target))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if else in your for loop is wrong, you should put your else outside of the for loop.

```
class Solution(object):
    def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        try:
            return nums.index(target)
        except:
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                print i
                if nums[i] - target > 0:
                    return i

            print "hello", len(nums)
            return len(nums)
```

However, bisect already contains everything you need.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
print(bisect_left([1,3,5,6],4))
```

As an exercice, you can try to do this exercise again, without using index, you might want to use enumerate and if else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Solution on Javascript

```js
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
    let l = 0;
    let r = nums.length - 1;
    let middle = Math.floor((r + l) / 2);
    if (nums[l] > target) return 0;
    if (nums[r] < target) return r + 1;
    while (nums[middle] !== target && l < r) {
        if (nums[middle] < target) {
            l = middle + 1;
        } else {
            r = middle;
        }
        middle = Math.floor((r + l) / 2);
    }
    return middle;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way to solve it. Following is my approach.

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        if target not in nums:
            nums.append(target)
            nums.sort()
        return nums.index(target)
```